# how to convert a ienumerable to list in converter mapping properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have a object as below.

```
public class person
{

  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set;}
}
```

I have a converter that converts a Ienumerable to list of this object. (By mapping these ID and Name from there (They also have ID and name only). How to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
using System.Linq;
```

...you should automatically have a `.ToList()` extension method for any `IEnumerable<>`:

```
IEnumerable<person> people = SomeMethod();

List<person> peopleList = people.ToList();
```